# Count return double value

Tags: mysql

We have small auction system and I add option to write some optional parameters for items (name of param and its value). Problem is when there are some params *COUNT(*) AS bids_count* return double value. Problem is in *auction_params* or *GROUP_CONCAT* function but I just can't figure it out.

```
SELECT a.*, u.user_nick, u.rating_positive, u.rating_negative, u.money_back, u.user_city, u.user_zip, u.user_country
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ap.param_name SEPARATOR '$concatSeparator') AS param_names
    ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ap.param_value SEPARATOR '$concatSeparator') AS param_values
    ,COUNT(*) AS bids_count, MAX(b.bid) AS last_bid
    ,(SELECT i.increment
        FROM increments i
        WHERE i.min_price <= IFNULL(MAX(b.bid), 0) AND i.currency = a.currency
        ORDER BY i.min_price DESC
        LIMIT 1)
        AS min_bid
    ,(SELECT u.user_nick
        FROM users u
        WHERE u.user_id = (SELECT user_id FROM bids WHERE auction_id = a.auction_id AND bid = MAX(b.bid))
        LIMIT 1)
        AS last_bid_user_nick
FROM auctions a
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.user_id = a.user_id
LEFT JOIN auctions_params ap ON ap.auction_id = a.auction_id
LEFT JOIN bids b ON b.auction_id = a.auction_id
WHERE a.auction_id = $auctionID
LIMIT 1
```

Thanks for help and sorry for english

Comment: Try `COUNT(DISTINCT b.id)`

Comment: How could I miss that? Thanks a lot, you are right.